# Apps are not supported in lesser than v5.0(lollipop)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

In android studio, i have create new project that run on 2.2(that shows 100% compatibility). The project is about calculation. I have installed on my phone(lollipop), and the app is working properly. But, I tried to install in my friends kitkat phone, the app is installed but, When i open the app, that shows Unfortunately the app has stopped. So, I need a help. What I have to do?

Thank You.

Comment: debug in kitkat you will find the issue,

Comment: How to debug in kitkat

Comment: plug your kitkat phone enable debug mode press debug button

Comment: I don't have kitkat phone

Answer (score 2):

May be you set Minimum SDK at Lollipop check it out in **build.gradle** file.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.communitynow.communitynow"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

and add
 `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'`
in gradle file

Here in defaultConig{} minSdkVersion should be 15 or according to your minimum android run requirement.

Comment: check in build.gradle(Module: app)

Comment: Thank You, I got it

Comment: In this there is minSdkversion 8

Comment: And the targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: Okay minSdkVersion is fine. Please check your theme and permission. May be it is the reason of error. Or upload more resources.

Comment: add line in your gradle file **compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'**

Comment: still not working after adding the compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' line....pls help me

Comment: Does the values folder have a version counter, Such as /values-v22? and try to add **android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"** this line in manifest activity tag. otherwise you have to upload error stack.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a kit kat emulator to run the app on then check the log cat to see what the error is.